# Drupal 7 hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() Submit

Tags: drupal-7

I am developing a custom module and used **hook_form_FORM_ID_alter** method. I have provided option same as in block's configuration visibility settings for specific pages. I have also created a database table for my module. I am not getting any idea how the options selected by user should be stored in my table when submitted and also how the option selected for a particular menu link should be retained. I have added this functionality on menu item edit form.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this is what you're looking for:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['my_val'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Some Text'
  );

  $form['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_my_form_submit';
}

function MYMODULE_my_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $val = $form_state['values']['my_val'];
  db_insert('my_table')->fields(array('val' => $val))->execute();
}
```

That's obviously a very basic example but it shows you how to add a submit handler to an existing form, how to add an extra field, and how to then get the data for that field in the submit handler.

Comment: Thanks I got that but for drupal 7 I think the submit function should be MYMODULE_submit($form, &$form_state)